# How to use aliases in ui-router?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router, aliases

I am using angular ui for routing in angular js.
I have a url like  http://servername/#/news/14.But I want to use aliases and have url like http://servername/#/news/news_title. Is it possible in angular ui??

Here is my config

```
angular.module('News', ['ui.router'])
  .config(function ($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
    $stateProvider
      .state('news', {
        url: "/news",
        templateUrl: "modules/news/views/news.html",
        controller: 'NewsCtrl'
      })
      .state('news.detail', {
        url: '^/news/:id',
        views: {
          '@': {
            templateUrl: 'modules/news/views/news_detail.html',
            controller: 'NewsDetailCtrl'
          }
        },
      });
  })
```

Comment: can you give the your config script?

Comment: I have updated the config in my question..

Answer (score 0):

Of course it is possible. But to make it happen, you need to somehow map the `news_title` to 14 which i guess is an `id`. You can write something like:

```
$stateProvider
    .state('news', {
        url: "/news/:news_title",
        templateUrl: 'news.html',
        ...
    })
```

in this case, you can type url like `http://http://servername/#/news/latest_bbc_news`, in your controller you can get the `:news_title` by using `$stateParams`

how you gonna map the `news_title` to `14` depends on your model.

## update

For example you probably can write something like this:

```
$stateProvider
    .state('news', {
        url: "/news/:news_title",
        templateUrl: 'news.html',
        resolve : {
          news_item: function(NewsService, $stateParams) {
            return NewsService.getByTitle($stateParams.news_title);
          },
        },
        controller:['$scope','$state','news_item',
          function ( $scope , $state , news_item){ 
            $scope.news_item= news_item;
        }]
     })
```

then in your `NewsService` you need to implement the method `getByTitle` to either get the news by title from backend directly, or you fetch all news from backend and cache it in a variable like

```
var news = [
  {ID: 1, Title : 'A', Content : 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX',},
  {ID: 2, Title : 'B', Content : 'YYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYY',},
];
```

and you have to write your own code to loop through it and find the news you need by title.

Again, ui-router is just setting up the routing rules for you, it is always your responsibility to serve the correct content. I mean ui-router have no idea which news have id 14 and the corresponding title, it can only be fetched from backend and processed by you.

Comment: I am just having the problems to map the news_title to news id ...can you provide me some solution??

Comment: you have a lot of options, for example, if you can send the :news_title directly to your backend, and let the backend find the news with the :news_title. or you can fetch all news together, and in your controller, you can loop through the whole array of news and find the news with the :news_title. you can also move this logic to your angular model if you want

Comment: I need solution through angular ui way. Does angular UI provide some feature to use aliases??

Comment: I actually don't really get the question, is it instead of using  `http://servername/#/news/14`, you want something like ` http://servername/#/news/breaking_news_a_b_c`? like you want to use news_title instead of using id in the url?

Comment: if that is the case, it is not something like alias, and angularjs wont have any clue of how to map the news_title to the news_id, because ui-router is just setting up a routing rules for you, but the content has to be connected and served by yourself.